# Parsing html element on ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am sending category_id from server script and getting ajax response like below,

```
<option value=''>---- Select ----</option>
<option category_id='26' value='1m'>test1</option>
<option category_id='26' value='3m'>test2</option>
<option category_id='26' value='12m'>test3</option>
```

I want to parse the option field to get the category_id value 26.
How can I achieve that???

this is my ajax function

```
 $.ajax(
 {
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/test",
    data:{groupname:name},
    success:function(response)
     {
     console.log(response);
    $("#duration").html(response);                                            
      }
       });
```

Comment: You are getting response in JSON or XMl

Comment: your ajax function ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are trying to do. all the `category_id`s have a value of 26. Can you please explain further?

Comment: do you mean a) you want to find out what category_id is for each option, or b) you want to find all the options where category_id = 26?

Comment: i just want to find the category_id from any option

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.attr()` function for that. Example: `$("option[value=1m]").attr("category_id");`

Comment: var x = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].getAttribute("category_id");

Comment: thanks to @kalsowerus i am able to find my required answer using following code $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("option[value=1m]").attr("category_id");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,
This will find the value of id "category_id" ending with value containg letter 'm'.
option[value$=m] , is jquery selecter for the above case

$($.parseHTML(response)).filter("option[value$=m]").attr("ca‌​tegory_id");

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will select the option element that has an id ending with 'm':

```
  $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("option[value$=m]").attr("ca‌​tegory_id");
```